# Image Layout in Posts

Tags: plugins, images

I was working on the company blog today and just had a question. Currently, the staff posts a blurb and then inserts images of the new products which makes the post really long. I was wondering if anyone knew of a plugin or knew of a way to get said images to be like 3 x 3.

Answer (score 3):

You can display attached images as [gallery](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) instead of individually.